# IDE for rails which works very similar to Pycharm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pycharm

I have recently shifted from rails to pycharm. I have tried Netbeans and Aptana Studio for rails development, but they don't work like python's pycharm. In them features like auto-saving, error marking, etc are missing.

Can you please let me know the best IDE for development on rails.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may be interested in [rubymine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/)

Answer (score 2):

You may consider [IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) with **Ruby** and **Python** plug-ins to get both [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) and [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) features in a single IDE (plus much more).

Otherwise just go for [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/).

IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate contains all the features of WebStorm, PhpStorm, PyCharm and RubyMine products in one (with minor exceptions like opening folders and creating projects directly from the remote servers).

Comment: You seem like the correct person to ask this - what is the relationship between IntelliJ IDEA (+python plugin) and PyCharm? Can IntelliJ IDEA behave as WebStorm, for example?

Comment: Posting as a comment as I feel this is related to the original question.

Comment: Updated the answer to address your question.

Comment: That's great, thank you. We're on the brink of buying more from JetBrains on the basis of Resharper being indispensable. :D

Answer (score 1):

[Rubymine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/), IDE from JetBrains - authors of PyCharm.